# what is the best way to store data in client side(angular js)?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller, which load huge data when controller load, but I do not want to fetch this data again and again when controller is loading. It will load only when the same data is modify or edited. here I am giving a scenario :

i have a controller `listController` when it load it fetch huge data from database. and it shows list of data in corresponding page(list.html). now when

1. I move some other page and again move to same page(list.html). In this case controller will again load and will fetch huge data, but I don't want to load this huge data. I want old data because it delays fetching data from DB and data is same not modified.
2. There is option for edit list of data. When I edit the same data(it is under different controller) and save. In that case it will redirect to list.html page and should be load huge data(because in this case data is modified).

I searched a lot i got that service is a good option for this, but is there any other way to do that. Is cache is good way to handle this ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: rather than storing huge data on client side, dont bring data to client side.. use pagination, get only as much data as needed

Comment: You are right @entre, but what if i will fetch huze data ?

Comment: As @entre said use pagination. I don't see any other option available other than caching. And also after modifying records you have to hit the DB to fetch modified records and there is no other way.

Comment: @MukundKumar consider scenario where multiple users might edit that data, how will you handle that?? its too complex... just use pagination...

Comment: @entre you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind advises to use pagination to prevent unnecessary pauses. Pagination is a common approach for distributed applications with massive data.

However if you find yourself still looking for a persistent client-side storage examine [angular local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is store the data in some parent controller, rather then listController( so that data is not fetched again on reload of list.html) and fetch data from this parent controller .

you should use cache also  like:

`$http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);`- this will cache the response.

You can custom implement it yourself using [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache) .

But its always better to store data in some database server (use mongodb for instance, its really smooth)